# Creating image grid using PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a problem about PHP coding. I manage to display the first 12 image nicely on the image grid but after that, the picture seems to be out of place.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='w3-quarter'>";
    }
    echo "<img src='images/{$row['image']}' onclick=onClick(this) style='width:100%'>";
    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
        echo"</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

[image: the gap after 12th picture]

I want the output to look like this
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiKt3.png)

and the css i using is w3-quarter from w3.css

Comment: You have to show us what you want the output to look like. Are you using any CSS grid frameworks?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: To handle this kind of issue with PHP, you have to know the image size ahead of time. Then you can do the math to determine how many will fit per row and column. Otherwise, you use JavaScript and CSS

Comment: @Sarcoma if i use masonry can i use PHP code as above? Because i need to retrieve all the image from my database